# Queuing jobs in a processing chain in Java

Tags: java, queue, jms, correlation

I am currently designing a correlation engine in java which is extracting data from pdf files and correlating (raising alerts where necessary) it structured data from a relational database.

Focusing on the processing of the pdf files the system consists of:

A component which is performing the custom extraction from the pdf.

A component which parses the sometimes unordered unclean data into the required data structures

A normalisation component which will normalises the values for comparison

And a component which interfaces with the db (where the extracted data will be inserted with the rest of the data)

The components should be reusable in other processing chains but they will all run on the same system initially.

I think it's wise to have some sort of buffering between components, is it wise to be using JMS Queueing or would this over complicate matters? I have been experimenting with a simple linkedblockingqueue object but this object has to be passed between components so it requires a master components which drives everything which i am not sure is desirable, is there a standard way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use chained calls unless you have additional requirements.

```
loadPDF(new PDFExtractor(new PDFParser(new Normalizer(new DBEnricher(listener)))));
```

If you want multiple threads, I would process each file in a different thread using an ExecutorService thread pool.

Comment: Is it fairly standard to include the queue object with each component for completed jobs and have the handlers pull from it or have the queue in a separate handler?

Comment: I would have one component call the other via a method call and return a result or throw an Exception when an error occurs. I don't see the need for a Queue.

Comment: The idea of using queues is that some of the jobs are going to be so processor and memory intensive it is better for those tasks to complete and results queued up so the resources can be released, also the queue can be consumed by multiple threads running concurrently

Comment: If you have only one PDF file and you need to process part of the file concurrently that is a useful thing.  However I suspect you can process multiple files concurrently i.e. you have more files than cores, and adding queue adds coding and processing overhead and is likely to be slower than a simpler solution.